# Why the protected router is not being recognised in statement even when it is true

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Currently, I am trying to protect a router so the user would only get access to that page before they filled in the registration form. Based on that condition it should redirect them to the page to see if they have the winning promotion code. But even when ProtectRouter.completeCheckProtect() is false, the user is still being redirected to the page, which is not the expected result I want in this case. Could someone look into this and help me further?

[Working CodeSandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu/generator-1)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectRouter from './ProtectRouter';

class Lose extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let test = () => {
            ProtectRouter.locked(() => {
                console.log(ProtectRouter.completeCheckProtect())
            });
        }
        let home = () => {
            ProtectRouter.locked(() => {
                window.location.href =  window.location.origin; 
            });
          };

          // console.log(ProtectRouter.completeCheckProtect()) returns true, but it is not being recognized inside the if else ststement....
          if(ProtectRouter.completeCheckProtect()) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>You Lose</h1>
                    <button onClick={test}>test</button>
                    <button onClick={home}>Home</button>
                </div>
            )
          } else {
              return (
                  <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: "/"
                  }}/>
                  
              )
          }
    }
}

export default Lose;

class ProtectRouter {

constructor() {
    this.checkProtect = false;
}

unlocked(cb) {
    this.checkProtect = true;
    console.log("unlocked");
    cb();
}

locked(cb) {
    this.checkProtect = false;
    console.log("locked");
    cb();
}

completeCheckProtect() {
    return this.checkProtect;
}
}
console.log('loading')
export default new ProtectRouter();
```

Comment: Can you put together an example in codesandbox.io or in codepen?

Comment: Check the added snippet